# Site-specific: Firefox vs. IE CSS peculiarities

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm trying to learn CSS. I've taken great pains to get everything right. My pages all validate and they look correct on Firefox and mostly correct on Chrome. However IE is all over the place. In relation to Firefox, the following is wrong in IE (in order of importance):

1. the main body box is pushed below where the left boxes end
2. the upper-right drop-down stuff (mouse over "Settings") is totally off in the weeds (it's off in Chrome also but in a different way)
3. "Recipes" tab is supposed to have no visible bottom border
4. search button is askew in relation to search box
5. logged out version: the upper-right login elements are askew

[Logged in](http://www.mcrackan.com/recipes/csstest-loggedin.htm),
[Logged out](http://www.mcrackan.com/recipes/csstest-loggedout.htm),
[CSS](http://www.mcrackan.com/recipes/css/default.css),

Links, functionality, etc. are not guaranteed to work on these pages. It's just static snapshots to show layout.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for whatever I'm doing wrong?

Comment: posting this as a comment so i dont get flamed, tables might work better for some of this stuff, especially the top div where you want to float left and right

Comment: I agree with you and have been very very tempted to do exactly that. However, as a novice, I'm trying to avoid tables on principle so I can make myself learn the arcane insanity that is CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to Reset your CSS (Dean, above recommends Eric Meyer's Reset CSS). I prefer [Yui Reset CSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) (I actually like their own Reset / Fonts / Grids CSS). As part of doing this you also need to use Standards Mode.

Finally, you need to be aware that some things will differ in browsers no matter what. So if you run into this situation, it's either work around it, or live with it.

Answer (score 1):

What version of IE are you running?  Sounds like most of your issues may be caused by the [IE Box Model](http://www.google.com/search?q=IE+Box+Model) Bug.

Comment: The only version of IE I have available to me is 7.0

Answer (score 1):

I never start a new website design in css without putting [Eric Meyer's Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html) in first.

It resets all the differences in all the browsers, so that you've got a even playing field to start from.
From there-out, everything should be the same in all browsers.